# How to know directly port SSH when server change its default?

Tags: ssh

When we change port ssh default (port 22) Example:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config (change port)
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2125 --syn -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2125
firewall-cmd --add-port 2125/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port 2125/tcp
service sshd restart
```

So how to scan server to know port ssh to brute force or make several following action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an attacker would need to perform a port scan (with Nmap or similar). Most of port scanning is for finding open known default ports for vulnerable protocols.

If you have open non-default ports, further investigation would be needed to detect the protocols. In the case of SSH every port would need to be connected to see whether it answers

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_<version> <platform>
```

or similar first answer line of SSH protocol. Only after that it would be possible to start any attack targetting SSH.

Most criminals are lazy and wouldn't bother to take these steps as there's plenty of fish in the sea: it's much more easy to brute force random servers with open default port `22`. It may also be more effective as admins using non-default ports may have also taken more other security measures. On the other hand this means that if you see all these steps performed, the attack is most likely targeted.

Using non-default SSH port may cause other problems to your users: It's not as easy to use as the port must be defined separately. Some firewalls may block the connection while SSH is allowed, because this kind of rules are defined with the default port. Therefore, non-default port may not be a good security measure. Fail2ban would be much better approach against the brute force attacks mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find open ports on your local machine I'd run:

```
netstat -plunt
```

If you want to find SSH port, run:

```
netstat -plunt | grep ssh
```

To find all TCP/UDP ports opened on a remote machine, run:

```
sudo nmap -n -PN -sT -sU -p- ip_of_remote_machine
```